# Wait the end of ng-repeat with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to load my JavaScript class after the end of ng-repeat.

*AngularJS version : 1.6.4*

**My JavaScript class :**

```
+(function($) {
  'use strict';
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-dialog="true"]');
    console.log(buttons.length); // return 0
  });
});
```

**My AngularJS view :**

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in filteredItems">
  <td>{{item.title}}</td>
  <td>
    <a href="/page/duplic/{{item.id}}" data-dialog="true"
       data-dialog-action-title="duplic item">file_copy</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

**Issue :** My JS class is loaded before the AngularJS render, and the `console.log()` return no elements.

Answer (score 0):

Inject the code with a custom directive:

```
app.directive("dialog",function() {
    return {
        link: postLink
    };
    function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
        var button = elem;
        console.log(attrs.dialogActionTitle);
        if (attr.dialog == "true") {
          //script here
        };
    }
})
```

The `postLink` function will be invoke by the $compile service after the `ng-repeat` directive appends the element to the DOM.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Creating Custom Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as an event for when `ng-repeat` finished. But angularJS creates the following attributes:

```
$first: true
$last: false
$middle: false
$even: true
$odd: false
```

You can check it using `$last` and a custom directive as following:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in filteredItems" isitthelastone>
    {{item.name}}
</div>
```

**APP.JS**

```
.directive('isitthelastone', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {

    if (scope.$last){
      alert('event triggered');
    }

  };
})
```